# Shiny Retrieve the data displayed from output$x

Tags: r, shiny

How I can retrieve the data displayed from output.

```
output$x <-renderDataTable(data ())
```

For reuse in other places

Comment: That's what reactives are for. Do your calculations in a reactive, and use that in multiple render statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Next time please specify Your problem better...**

Well You do have reactive data in the code and You actually called it/retrieved it by using: `data()` *****

*****(and if you wanna use it in another output simply type again `data()`)

I assume that You use `DT` package  (`renderDataTable`) in which You wanna filter primary data and retrieve it back? (i might be wrong due to the lack of detailed description of the problem)

To use the filtered data just simply use (as in Your case):

```
data_filtered <- reactive({
        filtered_data <- input$x_rows_all
        data <- data()[filtered_data, , drop = FALSE]
        data})
```